# Fixed & shrinking navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I didn't find anything on Google about this without using Bootstrap and in my project I didn't want to. (because I'm a beginner and I decided to start with a vanilla project - only css html and js and mostly because when I started building this I didn't even know what bootstrap was).
So how I can make the white (id: top-mare + logo) navbar fixed and shrinking while scrolling?

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Best DAVNIC73</title>
    <link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/sshow.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
    <link href="css/mqueries.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="shadow">
            <header id="top">
                <nav id="top-mic">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Despre noi</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Locatie</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="davnic" id="logo"></img></a>
                <div id="top-mare-wrap">
                    <nav id="top-mare">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Acasa</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Buton1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Buton2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Buton3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Buton4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
        <div class="slideshow-container">

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
                <img src="img/img1.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
                <img src="img/img2.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
                <img src="img/img3.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
            <script src="js/sshow.js"></script> 

            <button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Inapoi la inceputul paginii"><img src="img/arrow-up-01-128.jpg"/></button>
            <script src="js/myBtn.js"></script>
            <footer class="footer">
                <ul>
                    <li id="nume">SC Best DAVNIC73 SRL</li>
                    <li><img src="img/location_1.png" class="location"/> Judet Dambovita, Oras Targoviste, Strada, Nr</li>
                    <li><img src="img/phone.jpg" class="phone"/>074 44 44 444</li>
                    <li><img src="img/mail.jpg" id="mail"/>bestdavnic73@gmail.com</li>
                    <li class="copyright">Copyright Ⓒ 2017</li>
                </ul>
            </footer>     
            </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```html
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 6vw;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1.1vw;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

header {
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ADADAD;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#top-mic {
    background-color: #F28A00;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.73vw;
}

#top-mic ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
}

#top-mic li {
        float: right;
        padding: 0.416vw 1.5625vw;
}

#top-mic li a {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 0.6vw;
        font-weight: bold;
        transition: color 0.25s ease;
        margin-right: 2.8645vw;
}

#top-mic li a:hover {
    color: #ADADAD;
}

#logo {
 max-width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 12.5vw;
    margin-right: 6.77vw;
    width:15vw;
 height: auto !important;
}

#top-mare-wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#top-mare {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 3.125vw;
    
}

#top-mare ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}

#top-mare li {
        display: inline;
}

#top-mare li a {
        margin-top: 2.1875vw;
        margin-left: 2.083vw;
        padding-right: 1.041vw;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ADADAD;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 2.1vw;
        font-weight: bold;
        transition: color 0.25s ease;
}

#top-mare li a:hover {
        color: #F28A00;
}

#test {
    color:black;
}

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #F28A00;
}

.footer ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 1.041vw;     
}

.footer li { 
        font-size: 0.9vw;
        font-weight:bold;
        display: inline;
        margin-left: 2.604vw;
        padding-right: 0.78125vw;
        padding-bottom: 0.263vw;
}

.copyright {
    float:right;
}

#nume {
    font-weight: italic;
}

#myBtn {
    display: none; 
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 3.646vw; 
    left: 3.125vw; 
    z-index: 99; 
    border: none; 
    outline: none;
    background-color: #F28A00; 
    color: white; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    padding: 0.78125vw;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    width: 3.33333vw;
    height: 3.3333vw;
}

.location {
    width: 0.677vw;
    height: 0.677vw;
}

.phone {
    width: 0.677vw;
    height: 0.677vw;
}

#mail {
    height: 0.677vw;
    width: 0.9375vw;
}
```

Comment: It would be pretty cool if you could create a jsfiddle to get a fast overview of what exactly you are doing.

Comment: You reference a JS document (<script src="js/myBtn.js"></script>), but we're not seeing it in your posted code. Including that would be extremely helpful in seeing whats going on, assuming that doc contains your scroll functions.

Comment: That button redirects the user to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create shrinking animation I would suggest you to use CSS transition and jQuery addClass.

So, you're going to measure the scroll position from top. When at height wanted, add CSS class holding shrink values to that element.

For example your logo has class 'logo':

```
<img src="image/logo.jpg" class="logo"/>
```

Logo CSS:

```
.logo {
    width: 200px;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

The class you're going to add/remove is called eg. 'shrink'. It holds shrink values (eg you want the shrinking logo to be 125px wide):

```
.logo.shrink {
    width: 125px;
}
```

Next add shrink class to logo when needed (70px from top in this example).

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop > 70) {
        $('.logo').addClass('shrink');
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop < 70) {
        $('.logo').removeClass('shrink');
    }
});
```

I made you an example: https://jsfiddle.net/cr29y1tc/29/

Comment: Can you check my header and see how I've done it? I can't figure out how to do it only for the logo and "top-mare" nav.